# How do I open a file in Windows Phone 7.1?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I am just getting started on WP apps and my problem is that I need something similar to the `OpenFileDialog`, and I have been looking if there is tool like that on window phone and I read there is no tool like the OpenFileDialog.

I  do not know if there is anyone that could help with that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you r looking for the `Microsoft.Phone.Tasks` namespace.
there is nothing like `openFileDialog` or any generic file picker in wp7. But it'd be better to choose `CameraCaptureTask` or `PhotoChooserTask` for specific tasks.

just go with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks(VS.92).aspx

Comment: Thanks, now I´ve seen this problem everywhere, I used the photochoosertask but It only selects one picture, I need to select more than just one pic. I don't know if there is another tool besides the photochoosertask or what I can do to select more pictures at once